# JavaScript : NameSpace of a specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, namespaces

By using JavaScript, is there a way to know from which **namespace** does a specific **attribute** comes from ?

I can't seem to find anything relevant about this question...

**Exemple :**

A DIV element with a **class** attribute. From which **namespace** comes the **class** ?

A SVG element with a **viewBox** attribute. From which **namespace** comes the **viewBox** ?

**EDIT :**

If I wish to set a "xlink:href" attribute on a USE element, I'll have to specify the namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink".

What I'm looking for is something like : ***typeof attribute => namespace***

So... ***typeof "xlink:href" => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"***

I'm not asking/looking for a complete implementation that would retrieve this information.

Comment: Almost all attributes are in the null namespace.

Comment: getAttributeNS require the namespace and attribute, I'm actually looking for the namespace of that attribute... let me edit my exemples

Comment: And how do you get or retrieve that information Robert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the attributes via the attributes attribute and iterate it to get attribute names and namespaces. Most attributes will be in the null namespace.

```js
var attrs = document.getElementById("use").attributes;
for(var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
    console.log(attrs[i].name + " " + attrs[i].namespaceURI);
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <use id="use" xlink:href="something" class="something"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for ! Thanks a lot Robert